# How to write a REAL32 value to a file in Python?

Tags: python, ctypes

In wanting to create an [STL file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29), I need to write a REAL32 value to a file in binary IEEE floating point format.  How do I do this in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html)

```
with open(youroutput,'wb') as fout:
    fout.write(struct.pack('<f',300.0))
```

Here, `<` means little endian and `f` means float (32 bits, IEEE).

---

If you want to write multiple values in 1 go:

```
values = (300.0, 200.0, 100.0)
fout.write(struct.pack('<3f',*values))
```

Comment: How "typically" is float 32 bits in this context?  Can I reasonably expect this to work on most systems that support Python?  64 bit OS?

Comment: @devtk -- I think that's a pretty safe assumption these days.  Any system which supports IEEE should work.  If the system doesn't support IEEE, writing the data as IEEE seems pretty horrible ...

Comment: It is in fact guaranteed (at least in Python 3.3 which I asked). See the note (5) in the [table of format characters](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/struct.html#format-characters).

Comment: @delnan -- You're right.  I didn't look that closely.  It also says the same thing in the docs for python2.7.  Thanks for taking a closer look at that for me.

Comment: Yep, '<f' is guaranteed 32 bits and IEEE format.  In addition, '<h' will write a UINT16 and '<l' will write a UINT32 which are needed for STL files.  Thanks!